# TailwindCSS Image border

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to style an `image` element with a `border` style. But for some reason when I try to add more width to the border it does not get picked up by the browser on the the `image` element. It works fine on any thing else but when I add a bigger `width` size to the `border` I get an error.

Can anyone help out? This is my code below.

```html
<img src={'https://i.ibb.co/SnDDJ99/45219372-2219308534767966-7383583342043594752-n.jpg'}
  alt='Oscar Self Portrait'
  className="
    border-4
    w-1/2
    rounded-full  
    my-4
    md:w-4/12   
    md:p-4"
/>
```

If anyone has a solution that they can lead me too that would be great.

Comment: Same problem. It works on playground but not on actual code. If I add the border to a wrapper class then it works. How did you solve?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be working fine (see sandbox: https://play.tailwindcss.com/wTAwcVx1CH).

If you check the Tailwind docs, you can see that the only widths that are supported out of the box are 0, 1, 2, 4, & 8 (e.g. `border-8`). If you need other widths you can customize Tailwind by adding them to your `tailwind.config.js` file (https://tailwindcss.com/docs/border-width#customizing-your-theme) or, if you are using Tailwind 3.0, using the new arbitrary values format, e.g. `border-[5px]`.